# Cannot add or edit Joomla contacts from the administration

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In the administration side, in my components, and on the contacts page,  I cannot edit the contacts (add or save or close). The page is struck - all that I have to do is close the tab.
I tried in changing the permissions level too, but the issue remains the same.  Please suggest  to me some ideas.

Comment: And what did you do prior to that ? it's a bit difficult to guess...

Comment: Have you edited any of the Joomla core files or messed around with the database?

Comment: I did not do any thing prior ... this is a new template which i am working on..

Comment: I did not do any thing core files or touched the database, but i think the component is not working for me well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different solution: simply disable the osolcaptcha plugin while editing contacts. Most likely, contacts will not have to be updated very often.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it's too late but anyway... 
I had the same problem - the page just froze every time I tried to save or just close the contact page. In my case the problem had been caused by **osolcaptcha** plugin that intercepted any submits to form with `id="contact-form"`. So my solution was to make different ids for admin area and for my web-site's **contact us** page.